# how to make a .vhd file of an OS?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vhd

I have microsoft virtual PC 2007 installed in my windows 7 OS. I configured a new system from there giving RAM & HDD from the available installed OS (WIN 7).

but when i started a my Virtual PC, it showed the MAC address (some 16 digit number). I google it and found that although the OS is selected when configuring the virutal PC, one needs to install the same so as to start in virtual PC.

my Question: how to create a .vhd of any operating system. i might need Win XP/7/2008 to use as a virtual PC in my Win 7 OS (in desktop)

Let me know if any info needed.

thanks much!!

Comment: Not a single comment?

Comment: Tom is right. When you create a virtual machine, all you've created is a virtual computer. The virtual computer needs an operating system installing before it can do anything useful. Just like building a real computer, all you've done is assembled the (virtual) hardware at this point.

Comment: And as for asking for comments, please keep in mind that no-one here is *obliged* to help you, so its a little unreasonable to expect a response within 10 minutes. If you require that level of support then may I suggest some kind of paid contract with somebody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi it sounds like you have only created the machine, but not yet installed the operating system. So, when you see the MAC address that is the virtual PC looking for an MDT server or similar on the network to build from.
What you need to do is attach your physical DVD drive to the image and insert your Windows 7 or Server 2008 build disk in that. You could also just attach an ISO file to boot from.
Does that help?

Comment: thats correct. i had created machine and not installed the OS. but i am not sure from where to attach the ISO file of the OS. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yep, when the virtual machine is running in its window click on CD in the menu at the top and then "capture ISO Image". Then you just browse to the ISO location.
Reboot the virtual machine and it should boot from the ISO.

Comment: thanks that worked. But one last question: My company's server admin uses .vhd to import the OS instead of .iso. How to do that?

Comment: An ISO will be just an image of a CD/DVD.
A VHD is the file extension for the saved hard drive.

So, what this is means is that you can build a virtual machine using an ISO, install office, do all the windows updates and they get saved to the hard drive - which is in effect the VHD file. So, if you copy that VHD to another machine it will already have the OS/Office/windows updates done.